# Resolve dependencies with Castle Windsor using MEF in Visual Studio 2010 addin

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, add-in, mef, vspackage

I was wondering if there were best practices about using Castle Windsor with Visual Studio 2010 addin, which uses MEF internally to instantiate its controls, such as the `IWpfTextView`.

All the dependencies are registered when the VsPackage is created. How can I later resolve those dependencies when the `IWpfTextViewCreationListener` is created via MEF, sometime later? Should I expose the container as a singleton and access it, or is there a better way?

**Edit** Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. When the VsPackage is created, Windsor is wiring all the dependencies, which is, of course, what it does great.

My addin is a "Editor Adornment" type of extensibility, so after the solution is loaded and a code file is opened, I get a callback to my class which inherits `IWpfTextViewCreationListener` (and exported with `[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]` via MEF (which is done automatically by Visual Studio).

This happens in another context, that is, I don't have access to the VsPackage from this class, and any dependencies I need will not be initialized. So at this point I'm not sure how can I get those dependencies that were wired previously by Windsor.

Hope this makes it clearer.

(You can try creating your own extensibilty project using **File | New Project | Visual C# | Extensibility | Text Editor Adornment**, for example, to see how (and when) the `TextAdornment1Factory` is created.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Since the add-in is already composed by MEF it would make much more sense to just stay in that context.

Comment: @Mark I have updated the question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes, but why are you using Windsor there in the first place? Do you use it for *anything* else but composition? Do you use advanced lifetime management, typed factories or dynamic interception? If not, you probably don't need it.

Comment: @Mark I do all the wiring with Windsor when the addin starts, initializing my global dependencies there (something that talks to the DTE, for instance). Later, when the text editor control is created I need to access those globals somehow. Before using an IoC container, this global dependency was a singleton, so I could simply access it. Now it lives in the container, and I just like to access it. Hope this makes it clearer, otherwise I'm somewhat at a loss :)

Comment: Always keep this in mind about DI: most of the time you don't *need* a DI Container. Unless you do one of the above things (like interception), you could just as well be composing the object graph manually. If you think you need a container to "access stuff" it's essentially a Service Locator. In that case it's a design crutch that you can get rid of. Let your VsPackage [Import] what it needs and [Export] what other services need, and they can then [Import] those services.

Comment: @Mark I'm not using MEF directly - it's the way Visual Studio 2010 composes its components, and I have no control over when that happens. See, in this plugin there was a "poor man's service locator", which was essentially a static global dictionary of instances. I am trying to get rid of that, and replace it with a proper container. I haven't read your book yet, how do you deal with services that are created late, but need dependencies that already exist, unless they are global, or accessed via "service locator"?

Comment: Constructor Injection is the way you statically request Services. You shouldn't be doing that actively, but rather let the Composer supply them to you. Since your Add-In's already hosted by MEF, why not just let that compose your object graphs?

Comment: @Mark Because it was my understanding that MEF is not an IoC. I'm not sure I can use constructor injection with the component created by MEF, frankly I haven't tried - I haven't considered using MEF for this, since I'm not directly responsible and/or in control of the composition in Visual Studio.

Comment: MEF supports Constructor Injection, although you'd have to apply the [ImportingConstructor] to enable it. It's all explained in my book ;)

Comment: @Mark Alrighty, I'll try that :)